# Blank screen when running reactjs webapp in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm using Reactjs to create a browser based web application which interacts with MongoDB. Everything was working fine until I added webpack. Now, everything still seems to be working fine except when I try to run the application I get a blank screen.

I've went through my code and can't see what I've done wrong and after doing some online research I believe the issue could be caused by any number of things.

Are there any logs which could be used to help investigate this? Failing that, is there a recommended way to investigate this?

Comment: Do you know how to use Browser developer tools?

Comment: Thanks @konekoya. I'm new to this so didn't know to use Browser developer tools. I've found what the issue is using that. I'm not sure how to resolve it yet but will do some investigating before asking here.

Comment: No problem! You can edit your question and include the error that you've found as well as your example code. See this link for more info https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @konekoya stated, the Browser developer tools can be used to identify issues. In my case it showed the error that was preventing my browser from loading properly, I was then able to troubleshoot and solve my issue off the back of it.